# I am creating an android app and connecting it with the database. Android programming[ the new boston tutorial no 49-54]

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app and trying to connect it with the database. I am following TheNewBoston on Youtube for the code. I have successfully created the app.

**But when I run it, on Insert Query, my app hangs up and doesn't respond.**

Here is the code:

**MyDBHandler.java**

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "newproducts.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "products_table";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "product_name";


public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " +TABLE_NAME+ "("+
            COLUMN_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
            COLUMN_NAME+ " TEXT "+
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
public void add(Products products){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, products.get_productname());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    db.close();
}

public String dbToString(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String dbString = "";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+";";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(""+COLUMN_NAME+""))!=null){
            dbString+= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(""+COLUMN_NAME+""));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
}
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText mkInput;
TextView  mkText;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
public int dbVersion;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mkInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mkInput);
    mkText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    dbVersion = MyDBHandler.DATABASE_VERSION;
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, dbVersion);
    printDatabase();
}

public void addClicked(View view){
    Products products =  new Products(mkInput.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.add(products);
    printDatabase();
}
public void deleteClicked(View view){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"This is a toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = dbHandler.dbToString();
    mkText.setText(dbString);
    mkInput.setText("");
}
}
```

**Products.java**

```
public class Products  {
private int _id;
private String _productname;

public Products(String _productname) {
    this._productname = _productname;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public void set_productname(String _productname) {
    this._productname = _productname;
}

public String get_productname() {
    return _productname;
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mkInput"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="300dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mkInput"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:onClick="addClicked"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Delete"
    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="deleteClicked"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Default Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**Output Screen**
[This is the app interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX97C.png)

**On Clicking AddButton, App hangs up**

Comment: And where's your logcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `dbToString` code to this

```
public String dbToString(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String dbString = "";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+";";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

do{
    if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(""+COLUMN_NAME+""))!=null){
        dbString+= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(""+COLUMN_NAME+""));
        dbString += "\n";
    }
}while(cursor.moveToNext());
}

db.close();
return dbString;
}
```

Basically app is going in self loop now.

***Notice the difference of `moveToNext()`***. It would move the cursor to next position while `isAfterLast` just tells 
**whether the cursor is after the last result**.
[see](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isAfterLast())

Comment: Well, this code worked fine.
But Still there's a problem with your solution.

I've used this for a new database. and it is giving me this error.
 `E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.rajeshbharat.dbconnectivityrj1, PID: 29959
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rajeshbharat.dbconnectivityrj1/com.example.rajeshbharat.dbconnectivityrj1.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`

Then I've used while loop instead of while. and it is working fine.